# Apple I-tunes shows me error of IPV6 network if I am uploading detached react-native app using expo kit to implement in app purchase

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, expo, react-native-ios

When I am uploading react-native app to apple store it is showing me a error that app can't run on wifi over IPV6 Network.
I dont how to resolve the issue and this issue is created after detaching the app using expo kit. I had already uploaded one app (non-detached) and everything worked fine but after detaching it to use in app purchase of library "[react-native-iap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iap)" it is showing me error of ipv6 network error.

```
We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs when reviewed on iPad running iOS 12.1.1 on Wi-Fi.
```

More info:

```
When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used in production," you should validate against the test environment instead.
```

Comment: did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: No, I am still facing the same issue. However by making some changes in iPAD in expo app.json it passed the test.